# How to get a selected option's value

Tags: javascript, html

```
    function changeDay(monthSelect){
    dayVal = day.selected.value;
    //secili ayi al
    optVal = monthSelect.selected.value;
    if(optVal=='Şubat' && dayVal > 29){
        modifyDay(29);
    }
}
```

I get this error message for the line `dayVal = day.selected.value`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

how can i reach the selected option's value?

Comment: I would recommend looking at jQuery, it will make tasks like these much simpler and more organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to get the value:

```
day.value
```

And it works in all browsers, even IE 6

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/8xwhG/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "selectedIndex" property of the select element, and the "options" array:

```
var val = monthSelect.options[monthSelect.selectedIndex].value;
```

The option itself is what you get from the array:

```
var theOption = monthSelect.options[monthSelect.selectedIndex];
```

That's the only safe way to do it if you're dealing with older versions of IE (maybe all versions; I stopped experimenting on this a long time ago :-), but some browsers do make the "value" attribute of the select element track the selected option value appropriately.

Comment: `monthSelect.value` does the job too and is safe to use.

Comment: @roberkules well that may be true, but my reptile brain remembers that it didn't work in IE6.

Comment: ... or maybe it was old versions of Mozilla (like, pre-Firefox Mozilla).

Comment: Just checked it before with IETester, did work. Anyways, time to let go :)